# making animation of fading picture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to do a simple game , which the player should **tap** the pictures in a time limit 
and when the player taps the picture , i want to make animation of the picture **fading out**

I am using **Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone**

I think it's has something to do with `OpacityProperty`

Am not asking for the whole code to do it , i only want a helpful way to start

Comment: You should look at storyboards on msdn. Properly double animation, so you can do it precisely. You can also try with blend, where you can do the animation.

Comment: Do you want that image to disappear?(not exist anymore) or just to fade out (be invisible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `Storyboard` animation changing the `Opacity` of the image, something like

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageName"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"        
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"
        />
</Storyboard>
```