# assigning a storyboard for all objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to assign a Storyboard animation that i created to 16 pictures
Am working with **VS2012 Blend for Windows Phone**

The animation is about **fading Out** , so I did it for 1 picture to check if it works , and it worked , Now i need to set the `ControlPropetyAction` for each picture with that Animation

So i selected all pictures and Recorded the animation in Blend , but when i play it 
it makes **all** the pictures fade out ! but i only need each picture to fade out when it's get **Tapped** !

How i can do that ? (without having to do **16** Animation Types)

[image: Description]

Code for animation in XAML:

```
   <Image x:Name="pic1" Margin="12,33,372,562" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Assets/1395704999_red-21.png" Stretch="Fill">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource fadeOutAnimation}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Convert the animation to code. Here is [an example](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2013/12/15/Creating-simple-page-transitions-using-Storyboards-Slide-transition.aspx) on creating storyboards in code.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot but how i can see the Code in my project that Blend generated ?

Comment: Blend puts the Storyboard into XAML, either in the Page/Control you are editing, or in the App.xaml file. Open that up to see what blend generated

Comment: @ShawnKendrot i dont have such thing called Page/Control in BLEND

Comment: "page/control" = the page, or control that was open in blend (the xaml file).

Comment: @ShawnKendrot but i already saw the XAML code , i want to see how to do it in C#

Comment: XAML elements = C# classes. Transpose it yourself like in the post I referenced

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22611177/1054961), this is a sample of XAML you are using

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageName"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"        
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

This can be translated into code very easily.

```
var story = new Storyboard();
var animation = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), To = 0, From = 1};
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, YOUR_UI_ELEMENT_HERE);
story.Children.Add(animation);
story.Begin();
```

If you are subscribing to a Tap event of the elements, the `sender` is your UIElement

```
private void GridOnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs gestureEventArgs)
{
    UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
    // Call code above, replace YOUR_UI_ELEMENT_HERE
}
```